# Why aren't copulas unique for non-continuous random variables?

Tags: copula

I have read from the Sklar's theorem that for continuous random variables, then copula is unique. I really do not understand why? Could someone please explain to me why the copula not unique if the random variables are not continuous? If there is a peer reviewed paper, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341011 would be a duplicate but unfortunately does not have an answer yet